# Best way to use LINQ to SQL Contains() between a local List and a table

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Which is the better way to find the common items in a local list and a table in data base?

items or items2?

```
var clientId = 2;
// members is a local list, but not anonymous, like this
var members = new[] { 
    new { MemberId = "1", ... }, 
    new { MemberId = "2", ... }, 
    new { MemberId = "3", ... },
    new { MemberId = "4", ... },
    new { MemberId = "5", ... },// so on...
};

var items = db.MemberTable.Where(x => members.Select(s => s.MemberId).Contains(x.MemberId) && x.StoreId == storeId).Select(i => i.MemberId).ToList();

var items2 = members.Where(x => db.MemberTable.Where(c => c.StoreId== storeId).Select(s => s.MemberId).Contains(x.MemberId)).Select(i => i.MemberId).ToList();
```

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: for that to answer we´d need far more information, in particular your entities-schema. But even then this question would be pretty opinion-based, there´s no "right" or "whrong" unless you define what "better" means for you.

Comment: @CodeCaster faster?

Comment: Check the generated queries.  LINQ to EF can't do anything that can't be expressed in SQL. `db.Members.Where(member=>idList.Contains(member.ID))` is fast because it generates an `ID IN (id1,id2,id3)` clause. The first query looks like that except it's way too verbose - you gain *nothing* by creating the ID list inside `Where`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're assuming (as I do) that this is about EF, but it's tagged [linq-to-sql]. People often don't notice the difference.

Comment: @GertArnold doesn't L2S work the same with the `IN` clause?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It very picky as to when a local sequence can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ to SQL or LINQ to EF aren't magic. They  can't do anything that can't be expressed in SQL. Nor will they rewrite bad queries into a better form before generating SQL statments.

Unfortunately, when L2S (and some early versions of EF Core) can't generate the proper SQL statement, they'll try to load the rows and process them on the client resulting in *very* inefficient queries.

The way one would query items based on a list of IDs is to write :

```
select ID
from Members
Where ID in (1,2,6,7,9)
```

LINQ to EF/SQL can generate an `IN` clause *only* when Enumerable.Contains is used on a list of IDs, eg :

```
var ids=new[]{1,2,6,7,9};
var actualIDs = db.MemberTable.Where(x=>ids.Contains(x.ID));
```

The first query does that, in a verbose way. It's essentially the same as writing

```
var ids=members.Select(s => s.MemberId);
var items = db.MemberTable.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.MemberId) && x.StoreId == storeId)
                          .Select(i => i.MemberId)
                          .ToList();
```

This should generate this query :

```
SELECT MemberID
From Members
Where StoreId=12354 and MemberID in (1,2,5,8,9...)
```

This is a fast query, especially if `MemberID` and `StoreID` are indexed.

If LINQ to SQL is used, adding a `ToArray()` or `ToList()` to the local query may be needed. L2S was very finicky to say the least, and never meant to be anything more than a technology demonstration. Local performance is the same anyway, in both cases all IDs need to be read to construct the IN clause :

```
var ids=members.Select(s => s.MemberId).ToArray();
```

The second query is probably **very** *slow*  - it's not apparent what it does because everything is written in a single line and there's no way to see which part is the database query and which part is the local query. Rewriting it :

```
var items2 = members.Where(x => 
                  db.MemberTable
                     .Where(c => c.StoreId== storeId)
                     .Select(s => s.MemberId)
                .Contains(x.MemberId))
              .Select(i => i.MemberId)
              .ToList();
```

Shows that this executes this database query once for each item in the members list :

```
db.MemberTable
  .Where(c => c.StoreId== storeId)
  .Select(s => s.MemberId)
```

One would have to trace the SQL statements, but I suspect this is going to execute the following query over and over :

```
select MemberID
from Members
where StoreID=12345
```

It would be better (but not good) to rewrite this as :

```
var dbIDs=b.MemberTable
           .Where(c => c.StoreId== storeId)
           .Select(s => s.MemberId)
           .ToArray();
var items2 = members.Where(x => dbIds.Contains(x.MemberId))
              .Select(i => i.MemberId)
              .ToList();
```

This will still load unneeded rows and take extra database locks but at least it will do so only once.

Comment: For items 2 linq pad generates query like this for each ids: `DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = '1';DECLARE @p1 Int = 2;SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY] FROM [fc_Care] AS [t0] WHERE ([t0].[MemberId] = @p0) AND ([t0].[Client] = @p1) ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [value]`

Comment: As you said *for each ID*. That's still bad. Instead of a single query that would return the final results you get N queries. That's still N times slower than the first query

Comment: @FLash Linqpad's default is LINQ-to-SQL. What matters is what you work with in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ has method `list1.Intersect(list2)` to find common items. Probably works its best, remaining readable.
**Edit:** Works for equal objects by default. You can also pass any custom comparer as a second parameter in order to define how objects are treatened equal.

Comment: This is the slowest way possible - it will load all table rows before comparing them in memory

Comment: I believe if used like AsQueryable() it will produce pure SQL to get needed lines

Comment: What would that query look like? LINQ itself doesn't generate queries. The providers do and they can't generate queries for every LINQ expression. Using `Intersect` is no better than the OP's second query which is slow - it has to load all IDs for one store even if only a few of them are needed.